# How to format "time" in Job parameters in Hangfire?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, hangfire

My team has had this problem for a long time, and now it is my turn to give it a shot :
In Hangfire, in the parameters of a job that has been executed or has failed (Here, Jobs > Failed > Any job in the list > Parameters), you have this screen :

The time field:
[image]

see the "time" field ? It is not usable as it is. Would there be a way to format it as more readable for us ?

I haven't seen any related threads in forums or in the hangfire doc. I have tried changing the culture in my web.config. Doesn't work. I'm not even sure it is possible to format it without going inside hangfire's source code. I haven't seen this field properly formatted anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

> see the "time" field ? It is not usable as it is. Would there be a way to format it as more readable for us ?

If you check table `HangFire.JobParameter`, you would find the `Time` is stored with Unix timestamp format as below.

[image]

And the Unix timestamp is a way to track time as a running total of seconds. It represents the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1st, 1970 at UTC.

At the moment, HangFire just query from db and display this format time on dashboard page directly, and it seems that HangFire (v1.8.0 and older version) does not provide configuration options or extension methods to configure or customize this `Time` in **Parameters** section.

But under **State** section, we can get detailed time info of *Enqueue*, *Processing* and *Succeeded* states in Tooltip by hovering on execution time, like below.

[image]

If you'd like to convert Unix timestamp to human-readable datetime, you can achieve it in code `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(1682562344)`, or use online converter such as [this one](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).

[image]